# Python - Is there a way to wait os.unlink() or os.remove() to finish?

Tags: python, windows, wait

I have the following code:

```
os.remove('_Temp_Dir_\main' + str(i) + '.exe')
os.rmdir('_Temp_Dir_')
```

Which gives me:

```
OSError: [WinError 145] Directory is not empty: '_Temp_Dir_'
```

if i put the line

```
time.sleep(0.05)
```

before `os.rmdir()`, it works correctly. I think `os.remove()` isn't fast enough to remove the file. Any way to wait for it to finish its work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`shutil.rmtree()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to remove the directory and don't bother with removing the file:

```
import shutil

shutil.rmtree('_Temp_Dir_')
```

The `os.remove()` works just fine (it won't return until the file remove completes), there must be *other* files in that directory that the process left behind and are removed during your `sleep()` call.

Answer (score 3):

os.remove()` is a synchronous operation; when it returns, the file is definitely gone (unless it throws an error, of course).

The effect you see much be something else. I can imagine these effects:

1. Virus scanner
2. Desktop indexing

To find out what is going on, I suggest to use `os.listdir()` on the folder *before* you delete and print the result when `os.rmdir()` fails. The names in the list might give you an idea what is going on.